# error occurred during data insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

my code -

```
require 'database.php';
$uid = $_SESSION['UserId'];
$title = $_POST['imgtitle'];
$tag = $_POST['imgtag'];
$date = date("d-m-y");  

$q = "INSERT into album (`o_id`, `title`, `src`, `tag`, `date`)
VALUES('$uid', '$title', '$image_name', '$tag', '$date'";

$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if ($result) 
    {   
        echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Upload more...!</h1>";
    }
```

my `database.php`-

```
<?php

$db_name = "szdb";
$db_server = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";

$mysqli = new MySQLi($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error());

?>
```

**ERROR-**
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`

Comment: You should also be escaping your data, at the very least use `addslashes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket at the very end.

Change

```
$q = "INSERT into album (`o_id`, `title`, `src`, `tag`, `date`) 
VALUES('$uid', '$title', '$image_name', '$tag', '$date'";
```

to

```
$q = "INSERT into album (`o_id`, `title`, `src`, `tag`, `date`) 
VALUES('$uid', '$title', '$image_name', '$tag', '$date')";
```

Comment: Ah.. didn't see that.  That would be your problem, but still.. I'd check your POST vars.

Answer (score 0):

make sure all of your POST variables are coming through correctly

```
$userid = isset($_POST['userid']) && !empty($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid'] : null;
```